# How do I redirect with WebRequest?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0

I created a `WebRequest` to `POST` information. My objective is to emulate in C# a PayPal "buy now" button which is in html.

How do I get the redirect when sending the `WebRequest`? Simply having `Response.Redirect` doesn't work because I have to have the redirect *with* the information.

The code of the button I'm trying to emulate is:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do redirect with `post`.

What you can do: Make the actually post direct to the paypal, or redirect to a second page that re-create all the post data, and make automatic post with javascript.

An example of how to create a page with parameters that make automatic post.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks. And how do I activate that javascript?

Comment: Depends on what is your "event" that should trigger the POST. When do you want the POST to happen? In my case I needed it to happen immediately when my page came back from a postback so I added this piece of script on postback: `<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){ $('input#vAction').click() })</script>`

Comment: @ispiro Here is an example. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do what you want from code behind. I had a similar situation where I had the form like yours besides the normal ASP.net form. I hid the non-ASP.net form through CSS so it's not in the user's face and then I triggered the POST via javascript (I put a button inside the form and then called `buttonX.click();` )